# Caching of images/gradients?

Tags: qt, caching, qml

I have a `TableView` with around 40 rows and 4 columns. All of the 160 cells have a `Rectangle` with a gradient. I use Qt5.13 with enabled Quick compiler. Yet, when I animate all of these 160 cells in relatively large time intervals (100ms), the UI will become unresponsive. This means that rendering the gradients takes too long. In fact, if I only render 40 of such cells, I can update in 100ms intervals with ease.

The rectangles represent progress bars. They have gradients from top to bottom. However, the value (length) of the progress bars changes the gradients, too. This is why for each value (length) point, the gradients have to be recreated and rerendered.

Clearly, this is slow. What I would like to do is have the gradients being cached for each value (length) point. They represent percentages, so I would only need to cache 101. I am quite certain that this improves the performance here.

However, *how* can I cache gradients (or any objects) myself in QML? The more general (or bonus) question is: how can I have a shared QML resource between multiple QML files?

Comment: how are you creating your rectangles? if you share the code of the rectangle and its animation, it'd be easier to see the issue. It could simply be the way you're creating your objects (shrugs)

Answer (score 0):

You can try and load images instead of rendering if you have access to a large memory. Maybe you can also try scaling SVGs.